# How to rotate around an object without using unity's built-in functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to rotate a cube around a 1x1 pipe with arrow keys. (left and right).

The problem is i cannot use built-in functions which sets transform's position and location directly. (Such as transform.lookAt, transform.Rotate or transform.RotateAround). Because I need the vector values of rotation's euler and position for multiple stuff before i modify the value of the transform i want to rotate.

I tried different techniques but no luck so far.

I tried using sin-cos for rotating but could not figure out how to make it work for both rotation and position.

```
 _timer += Time.deltaTime * _larvaSpeed;
 float x = -Mathf.Cos(_timer) * distanceBetweenCenter;
 float y = Mathf.Sin(_timer) * distanceBetweenCenter;
```

Here is what i want to achieve. By pressing right or left, move and rotate the object around the pipe.

[image: The thing i want to do]

The result i want. (If i pressed right arrow key a litte bit).

[image: final result]

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: connect this cube as childe with an empty game object and rotate this empty game object

Comment: As i said, i need the math behind it.

Comment: you can do it using some function on unity, about the mathimatic way and math behind: you can use x^2 + y^2 = r2 to achieve this, x and y are the moving axis and r is the radius (distance between the cube and the center on the pipe)...all you have to do is keep this equation true and "r" always constant... let's say we start with x = 0 and y = 4, on the second frame, reduce y like .1 and using this x^2 + y^2 = r^2, get the new value of x, then transform.position = (new x, new y , z);...... i will set the script on the answer

Comment: I would be verry happy if u could show me an example about how to set position and rotation of an object using your math.

Comment: I'm working on it...

Comment: Why do you need the math for it?

Comment: for centre position, you use trigonometric sin and cosine multiplied by a radius depending on what you consider your starting angle. For rotation, you can simply use the angle for one axis can you not?

Comment: @Immersive I will use rotation and position values to play some particles and animations on the future position and rotation of the moving cube. Because of that i need the values before i set the cube's position and rotation. Also i'll add dragging ability to the cube etc.... If i do not do this in the right way, it is going to be really hard to manage all these things.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari You're actually right. I did the part for the position but could not figure out how to solve for rotation. I'm not so good at Quaternion stuff. :)

Comment: When I did it I just played around with angles and the inspector at runtime. Assuming you are only rotating on one axis that is fine. Otherwise it might require more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution using circle mathematics and I strongly recommended not use it, it's just to understand the circular move using circle equation as @FaTaLL ask in the comments

Circle equation...
(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 = r^2

x1, y1 is the cube position

x2, y2 is the pipe position

r is the distance between cube and pipe;

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotating : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pipe;
    public float Delta;
    Vector3 nextpos;
    bool compareY;
    bool next;
    int switchx;
    float storeVarAxis;
    float x, y, r;
    private void Start()
    {
        next = true;
        switchx = 1;
        compareY = true;
        x = transform.position.x - pipe.transform.position.x;
        y = transform.position.y - pipe.transform.position.y;
        storeVarAxis = y;
        r = Mathf.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (next)
        {
            if (compareY == true)
            {
                y -= Delta * Time.deltaTime;
                if (y <= -storeVarAxis)
                {
                    y = -storeVarAxis;
                    compareY = false;
                    switchx = -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                y += Delta * Time.deltaTime;
                if (y >= storeVarAxis)
                {
                    y = storeVarAxis;
                    compareY = true;
                    switchx = 1;
                }
            }
            float v = r * r - y * y;
            x = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs(v));
            nextpos = new Vector3(pipe.transform.position.x + x * switchx, pipe.transform.position.y + y, transform.position.z);
            next = false;
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextpos, 1f * Time.deltaTime);
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nextpos) < .05) transform.position = nextpos;
        if (transform.position.x.Equals(nextpos.x) && transform.position.y.Equals(nextpos.y)) next = true;
    }
}
```

well, the recommended way is using this simple script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotating : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public GameObject pipe;
    float r, angle;
    Vector3 startpos;
    private void Start()
    {
        r = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - pipe.transform.position.y);
        angle = 0;
        transform.position = pipe.transform.position;
        startpos = transform.position;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        angle = angle + speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.EulerAngles(0,0, angle);
        transform.position = startpos + (transform.rotation * new Vector3(r, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're legend!!. This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for your time and the explanation.

Comment: always in service!

Answer (score 2):

I think Quaternion * Vector3 is what you are looking for.  Luckily the box's rotation in its own local coordinates is the same rotation you need to apply to the box's position.

```
public float speed; //how fast to rotate
public float radius; //radius of the cylinder
public float angle; //angle around it

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        angle = angle + speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        angle = angle - speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }


    //figure out the rotation (from euler angles i guess??)
    var quat = Quaternion.EulerAngles(new Vector3(0, angle, 0));

    //ok uh what is the box position?? lets just multiply
    var unrotated_position = new Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
    var rotated_position = quat * unrotated_position;

    this.transform.position = rotated_position;

    //oh yea and also rotate the box in its own local coordinates
    this.transform.rotation = quat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution works very good.